# How to load a pickle file from S3 to use in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pickle

I am currently trying to load a pickled file from S3 into AWS lambda and store it to a list (the pickle is a list).

Here is my code:

```
import pickle
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
with open('oldscreenurls.pkl', 'rb') as data:
    old_list = s3.Bucket("pythonpickles").download_fileobj("oldscreenurls.pkl", data)
```

I get the following error even though the file exists:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'oldscreenurls.pkl'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As shown in the documentation for [`download_fileobj`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_fileobj), you need to open the file in binary *write* mode and save to the file first. Once the file is downloaded, you can open it for reading and unpickle.

```
import pickle
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
with open('oldscreenurls.pkl', 'wb') as data:
    s3.Bucket("pythonpickles").download_fileobj("oldscreenurls.pkl", data)

with open('oldscreenurls.pkl', 'rb') as data:
    old_list = pickle.load(data)
```

`download_fileobj` takes the name of an object in S3 plus a handle to a local file, and saves the contents of that object to the file. There is also a version of this function called [`download_file`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file) that takes a filename instead of an open file handle and handles opening it for you.

In this case it would probably be better to use [S3Client.get_object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) though, to avoid having to write and then immediately read a file. You could also write to an in-memory BytesIO object, which acts like a file but doesn't actually touch a disk. That would look something like this:

```
import pickle
import boto3
from io import BytesIO

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
with BytesIO() as data:
    s3.Bucket("pythonpickles").download_fileobj("oldscreenurls.pkl", data)
    data.seek(0)    # move back to the beginning after writing
    old_list = pickle.load(data)
```

Comment: EDIT: I don't know how to use code blocks in comments.
I read this and tried the get_object route before you posted your example and the code below worked! Thanks!

    response = s3client.get_object(Bucket= "pythonpickles", Key= "oldscreenurls.pkl")
    
pickled_list = response['Body'].read()
    
old_list = pickle.loads(pickled_list)

Answer (score 56):

Super simple solution

```py
import pickle
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_pickle = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket("bucket_name").Object("key_to_pickle.pickle").get()['Body'].read())
```

Comment: I like this answer as it is working, simple, and straightforward.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Makes pkl on s3 almost as accessible as the pd.read_csv integration of s3 paths.

Comment: its says there is no attribute names Bucket in s3 :/

Answer (score 16):

This is the easiest solution. You can load the data without even downloading the file locally using **S3FileSystem**

```
from s3fs.core import S3FileSystem
s3_file = S3FileSystem()

data = pickle.load(s3_file.open('{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, file_path)))
```

Comment: For this by default it wont have s3fs module/package so we would need to package, zip , upload, unzip and deploy :/

Answer (score 0):

According to my implementation, S3 file path read with pickle.

```
import pickle
import boto3

name = img_url.split('/')[::-1][0]
folder = 'media'
file_name = f'{folder}/{name}'
bucket_name = bucket_name
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
body = response['Body'].read()
data = pickle.loads(body)
```