# Load a NetworkX gpickle from S3 into AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pickle, networkx

As the title says, I am trying to use Amazon lambda to load a NetworkX graph from S3 and I would like to use a gpickle because it is a much smaller file size than the JSON.  I was able to load the JSON version of the network just fine using a slight adaptation of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964181/how-to-load-a-pickle-file-from-s3-to-use-in-aws-lambda).  However, when I try to adapt it to use the NetworkX gpickle command like this:

```
import boto3
import networkx as nx

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_graph = nx.read_gpickle(s3.Bucket("bucket_name").Object("key_to_pickle.gpickle").get()['Body'].read())
```

It doesn't work.  Specifically I get a `TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes` error which doesn't help me figure out what is wrong/different with the gpickle case.

This might be something specific to the NetworkX gpickle method.  Or it might be something general to AWS lambda reading files form S3.  How do I load my gpickle data from S3 into lambda?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code for NetworkX and found that it just calls `return pickle.load(path)` when using `read_gpickle(path)` in `mode=rb`.  So the problem is that NetworkX wants a file name, but AWS lambda can't do it that way.

It doesn't seem that the NetworkX method is doing any extra work to turn the response into NetworkX graph data.  That is, if NewtorkX is just using `pickle.load(path)`, then I guessed it would work with using `pickle.loads(data_object)` directly.  I tried:

```
my_graph = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket("bucket_name").Object("key_to_pickle.gpickle").get()['Body'].read())
```

and it works.  The results are indistinguishable form loading the JSON from S3 and loading the gpickle locally using Network's method.

Rather than delete my question, I decided to post it here with an answer so that future people can save time in loading network data into AWS.