# Load Python Pickle File from S3 Bucket to Sagemaker Notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have attempted the code on the many posts on how to load a pickle file (1.9GB) from an S3 bucket, but none seem to work for our notebook instance on AWS Sagemaker.  Notebook size is 50GB.

Some of the methods attempted:

Method 1

```
import io
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
bytes_buffer = io.BytesIO()
client.download_fileobj(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=my_key_path, Fileobj=bytes_buffer)

bytes_io.seek(0) 
byte_value = pickle.load(bytes_io)
```

This gives:

[image]

Method 2: This actually gets me something back with no error:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
bytes_buffer = io.BytesIO()
client.download_fileobj(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=my_key_path, Fileobj=bytes_buffer)
byte_value = bytes_buffer.getvalue()
import sys
sys.getsizeof(byte_value)/(1024**3)
```

this returns: 1.93

but how do I convert the byte_value into the pickled object?
I tried this:

```
pickled_data = pickle.loads(byte_value)
```

But the kernel "crashed" - went idle and I lost all variables.

Answer (score 3):

(in hindsight the solution was obvious, but wasn't to me on my first day in AWS Sagemaker world)   ... a memory error means you need to increase the size of your notebook instance.

In this case, sizing up the On-Demand Notebook Instance from ml.tx.xlarge (2vCPU, 8Gib) to ml.tx.2xlarge (4vCPU, 16Gib) worked.  See [Amazon SageMaker Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) for notebook instance CPU/Memory specifications.

In an earlier attempt to fix the problem, we had increased the volume size but that is for storage of data and didn't help with memory (see [Customize your notebook volume size, up to 16 TB, with Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-your-notebook-volume-size-up-to-16-tb-with-amazon-sagemaker/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20storage,GB%2C%20in%201%20GB%20increments.) for more details on storage volume); so we were able to decrease the volume size from 50 GB EBS to 10 GB EBS -

Memory can be monitored by opening up a terminal using the Jupyter interface and typing the linux command `free`

To load the picked dataframe, I simply used the solution from @kindjacket in this post: [How to load a pickle file from S3 to use in AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964181/how-to-load-a-pickle-file-from-s3-to-use-in-aws-lambda), which was as follows:

```
import pickle
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_pickle = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket("bucket_name").Object("key_to_pickle.pickle").get()['Body'].read())
```