# How to read pickle file from AWS S3 nested directory?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pickle

I have a pickle file in a nested directory inside AWS S3 Bucket, but I'm not able to load it with `boto3` library to use it with AWS Lambda.

I've tried to follow the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48964181/13695889), but no one works. This is my code so far:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
source_bucket = "source_bucket_name"
key = "folder1/pickle_file.p"
response = s3.Bucket(source_bucket).Object(key).get()
body_string = response['Body'].read()
try:
    loaded_pickle = pickle.loads(body_string)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

### EDIT

When loading this function into AWS, I'm getting the following error message:

```
embedded null byte
```

Comment: " I'm not able to load" - it is not specific. What exactly is happening. Any errors?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I've added the error message as an edit of the originial question. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not a valid python. This is wrong: `'source_bucket: "source_bucket_name"`' I would suggest providing a code that actually represents your issue.

Comment: Sorry @Marcin. That was a mistake that I made unintencioanally when writing the question. Now it's corrected. That is the code that I'm using I'm using in the lambda, so it's a valid Python code

Comment: https://www.internetkatta.com/search-file-or-folder-in-nested-subdirectory-of-s3-bucket see this can help you @marsolmos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine apart from what I said in the comments. Maybe your upload to S3 is incorrect then. below is full working example:

```
import pickle
import boto3

mylist = [1,2,3]

# create pickle file

with open('/tmp/pickle_file.p', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(mylist, f)

# upload to s3

source_bucket='source_bucket_name'
key = "folder1/pickle_file.p"

with open('/tmp/pickle_file.p', 'rb') as f:

  response = boto3.client('s3').put_object(
      Body=f,
      Bucket=source_bucket,
      Key=key)

  print(response)

# read back from s3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
response = s3.Bucket(source_bucket).Object(key).get()

body_string = response['Body'].read()

try:
    loaded_pickle = pickle.loads(body_string)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# should print out `mylist`
print(loaded_pickle)
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for the help. This answer has solved partially my problem. Thanks to this I've discovered that my pickle file was somehow "corrupted". I created my pickle locally and, later, I uploaded it to S3. This makes the pickle to search for the paths and dependencies from the environment where it was created (local environment) and thus it fails loading in Lambda environment. I haven't used pickle too many times, and I thought that it didn't matter where and how the file is created, but it looks like it's very important. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: @marsolmos No problem. Glad it worked out:-)